# How to upload a 3gp file on SDcard to a server?

Tags: android, file, http-post, send

After countless headaches and time wasted I managed to get the AudioRecorder working for Android and have a file stored on my SDcard. What I want to do now is send this file to a server within the application. So when the user hits submit...it sends the .3gp file. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible. What server is that? What protocol do you want to use? FTP? A proprietary socket that just sends the raw data via FTP?

Comment: What do you suggest is best? I had FTP in mind. I'm new to server side coding so I'll look into whatever is suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you just use HTTP and POST it to your server.

Here's a good little code snippet that shows how to do an HTTP post from java.

http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/HttpUpload

Then you'll have to receive the file on your server. You could just use a simple php script for that unless you have some other server side technology.

Here's some documentation for doing this using php:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Answer (score 2):

yes you should use FTP because it will be faster...

I had done bit R&D on it and found few link but most of them were not working.
here is the link that is working for FTP upload..

http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/